# How to fix Unexpected string in JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

This error message keeps coming up

> "This policy contains the following JSON error on line ?: Unexpected
>   string in JSON at position 195"

I have tried to debug and looked for solutions but no success yet.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "vmie.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      "condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId":"vmimportating"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Comma is missing between Action and Condition objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you format that JSON, you would see the error.

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Service": "vmie.amazonaws.com" }, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole" "condition": { "StringEquals": { "sts:ExternalId":"vmimportating" } } } ] }
```

there should be a comma `,` between `Action` and `condition`

**Note: condition needs to have capital `C`. So, use `"Condition": ...`**

Comment: Hi, i did fix that and now i'm getting "An error occurred: Unknown field condition
"

Comment: try using capital `C`: Condition

Answer (score 0):

Use any online formatter. You are missing a comma after `"Sts:AssumeRole",`

Add that and it validates

I like to use [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

Comment: Hi, i did fix that and now i'm getting "An error occurred: Unknown field condition
"

Comment: Paste what you have

Answer (score 0):

Validate your json using online tools like
[online json validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Correct json is:

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{  
            "Service":"vmie.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
         "condition":{  
            "StringEquals":{  
               "sts:ExternalId":"vmimportating"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, i did fix that and now i'm getting "An error occurred: Unknown field condition
"